# using expression in *ngIf angular2

Tags: angular

I am wondering if I can use function return value in *ngIf in angular2.

I am trying

```
<ion-fab right bottom *ngIf="shouldDisplayFlag()">
```

It is giving error.

Comment: That is possible yes. Please share the error you are getting.

Comment: what does `shouldDisplayFlag()` return?

Comment: "It is giving an error" is quite useless. The exact error message would be rather valuable :D

Answer (score 0):

NgIf evaluates the `expression` like truthy or falsy value so if `shouldDisplayFlag()` return value truthy the elemnt will be render and if the value falsy or the function doesn't return value the element remove from the dom.

[NgIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf)